# Use "Face Recognition" (lib) to recognize new face between 100k existing faces?

Tags: python, machine-learning, face-recognition

I want to use the ["Face Recognition"](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#face-recognition) lib to recognize a new face. I have a dataset of 100k users with each of them 3-5 images. I don't exactly understand how to use this library.

There is this method:

```
import face_recognition
known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("unknown.jpg")

obama_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]

results = face_recognition.compare_faces([obama_encoding], unknown_encoding)
if results[0] == True:
    print("It's a picture of Obama!")
else:
    print("It's not a picture of Obama!")
```

Do I have to iterate over all the images (100k users*5images) to "identify" the person in the unknown image? Or do I save all the `face_encodings()` of each image in the database and then do a search in the database with the face_encoding of the new image? And if this is so, this method doesn't benefit from the fact that my dataset has 5 different images of the same person?

This library is from [@ageitgey](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78) he describes another method with OpenFace and dlib in this [article](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/machine-learning-is-fun-part-4-modern-face-recognition-with-deep-learning-c3cffc121d78), where the CNN calculates the 128 measurements from the 5 images of the person combined. (Scroll down to Step2) - Which Method is better? I couldn't find this functionality with the "[face recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition#face-recognition)" lib.

Comment: According to the examples, this seems to be a very reduced or badly designed lib. Not sure if adding the missing steps to this pipeline is possible (to not check all pairs; e.g. usage of SVM-classification). Openface is probably much more open to this and should also have an example for SVM-based classification (and the general approach of face -> point in metric-space has some advantages).

Answer (score 1):

If you use dlib within deepface, you don't have to build a for loop to do this task.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
df = DeepFace.find("obama.jpg", db_path = "C:/my_db"
   , model_name = 'dlib', detector_backend = 'dlib')
print(df.head())
```

It will look for the identity of img1.jpg in my_db folder.

You can apply face verification for image pairs as well.

```
from deepface import DeepFace
obj = DeepFace.verify("obama.jpg", "unknown.jpg"
   , model_name = 'dlib', detector_backend = 'dlib')
print(obj["verified"])
```

Besides, you can adopt VGG-Face, Google Facenet, OpenFace, Facebook DeepFace, DeepID instead of Dlib as well.

```
models = ["VGG-Face", "Facenet", "OpenFace", "DeepFace", "DeepID", "Dlib"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on similar project as yours. You have to train your image dataset with the library .Choose a set of images to train and place it in a folder. Make sure to label the images after the person's name. Now choose a set of test images(unknown images) which are not part of your training images and keep it in a folder.

Then you simply run the command face_recognition, passing in the folder of known people and the folder (or single image) with unknown people and it tells you who is in each image:

```
$ face_recognition ./pictures_of_people_i_know/ ./unknown_pictures/

/unknown_pictures/unknown.jpg,Barack Obama
/face_recognition_test/unknown_pictures/unknown.jpg,unknown_person
```

There's one line in the output for each face. The data is comma-separated with the filename and the name of the person found.

Comment: Skimming through the code it seems this will still do pairwise-checks. Can you confirm this (will not scale well)?

Comment: @sascha Yes this will need some efforts when running through a large set of files. But since he has 100's of files . It gets trained well and should work

Comment: so I can't use multiple images of the same person? or can I also make a folder for each user and put every image of a user in the folder called after the person? => When you look scroll down the article I linked, with OpenFace you can benefit from every image of a person. Here you don't?

Comment: @Suisse Technically openface (used on your images) does not exploit multiple images of some given person (it just maps every face to some other domain), but the surrounding pipeline does if you want. So given some discrimination-based classifier, the whole pipeline will do.

Comment: @Suisse . Yes use a bulk operation to store all the images of a person under each folder and that becomes your label. You can still benefit from every image of a person. Infact you are giving your classifier more data to get trained